# syntax error with python code

Tags: python, syntax

I have this function in my class:

```
 def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      if user in self.users:
         for k in self.users.keys():
            if k == user:
               del self.users[k]
               print("Removed")

            else:
               print("user does not exist")
      else:
         print "soemthing"
```

now I always get error at this last `else`  with message: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
where as it should work. users is a dictionary here and there is no other method. Why am I getting this syntax error?

Comment: What python version? If 3+, this needs to be `print()` as your other ones are.

Comment: why do you do the for `k in self.users.keys`  instead of just `self.users.pop(user)` in fact you can use pop even if the key doesnt exist so you can get rid of that whole if

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  In Python 3, `print` is a function: `print("Something")`

Comment: check your code for uncorrect indentation, unclosed parentheses and some forgotten whitespace.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: the syntax error would be on the `print` line, then, not on the `else:` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation could be incorrect, most likely caused by tabs. Run `python -tt scriptname.py` to check.

There is otherwise no syntax error in your code that would cause this *specific* exception, not in the code you've given us.

Comment: oh thanks, that was really the case, i just reset the indentation manually and it works now. Can you tell me a good IDE Please to work with python

Comment: @Sara: IDLE is the default IDE for Python. Many Pythonistas work without IDEs, though, preferring an editor in conjunction with IPython.

Comment: @Sara: Anything that can be configured to use only spaces instead of tabs is fine.

Comment: eclipse + pydev is flat out the best imho ... ninja ide is lightweight and nice ... notepad++(and/or scite) is lightweight and pretty good

Answer (score 3):

you can simplify this alot by

```
def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      return self.users.pop(user,False)
```

or

```
def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      if self.users.pop(user,False):
         print "%s was deleted from group"
      else:
         print "%s is not in group"
```

or

```
def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      userData = self.users.pop(user,False):
      if userData: 
          #do Something
      else:
          #do something else
```

or lastly

```
def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      try:userData = self.users.pop(user):
      except KeyError:
          #user does not exist in dict
          pass
      print "Deleted {0}:{1} From List".format((user,userData))
```

apparently (per denlan and I believe it)  `del` is fine to use

```
def removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      try:
         del self.users[user]
         print "Removed user"
      except KeyError:  
         print "User does not exist" 


def alt_removeUserFromSessionDatabase(self, user):
      if user in self.users
         del self.users[user]
         print "Removed user"
      else:  
         print "User does not exist"
```

Comment: Well, except for the output. But yeah, the loop is complete nonsense. As Larry Wall put it: "Doing linear scans over an associative array is like trying to club someone to death with a loaded Uzi."

Comment: there now it accounts for the output :P

Comment: Unfortunately, that's wrong, because `.pop` (1) returns the values associated with the removed key, not a boolean (and that object may be falsy) and (2) it raises a `KeyError` if `user not in self.users` rather than returning something falsy.

Comment: there fixed by giving default val (but you are right about the value could be false/none...but in this case it sounds like that would not be a factor

Comment: Still, no need to introduce such a subtle assumption, and no need to obfuscate by putting a side effect into a condition. What the heck is wrong with checking if `user in self.users` and using `del self.users[user]` in one of the branches?

Comment: nothing this just felt more "pythonic" to me ... besides del doesnt always work quite how you think it would... (It should in this case but..)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16447/discussion-between-delnan-and-joran-beasley)

Comment: thank you for detailed answer and it is very helpful., i just selected other answer as accepted as it was the first one and solved my original question, but thanks again i have used your suggestion to shorten what im doing., +1

Comment: Yeah its ok I didnt exactly answer the original Question... but i felt it worth an answer anyway